# How to get image in image tag from MYSQL database in React JS?

Tags: reactjs

[Here is the image path where I stored my Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvFow.png)

**As you can see I am trying to get images from the database using Axios get method but the issue is image is getting ok in the products.js file but not display in the image tag and product.js component.**

**products.js**

```
<div className={classes.imggrid}>
            <Grid container fluid spacing={2}>
                {props.orders.map(order => (
                    <Grid key={order.id} item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
                        <Product
                            id={order.id}
                            ProductImage={`/uploads/${order.image}`}
                            ProductName={order.name}
                            ProductPrice={currencyFormatter.format(order.price, { code: '' })}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                ))}
            </Grid>
</div>
```

**Product.js**

```
  <div className="container">
            <div className="cards-slider">
                <div className="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <div className="card overflow">
                       <Link to={`/details/${props.id}`}><img className="card-img-top overflow" src= 
                        {props.ProductImage} alt="Card images" /><br /></Link> 
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <h3 className="card-title">{props.ProductName}</h3>
                            <p className="card-text">{'Rs '+props.ProductPrice}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                       <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger btn-lg col-md-12 rounded-0" >Add 
                        to cart</button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try `console.log(props.ProductImage)` in your Product.js file and check if you are providing a valid url for the image

Comment: /uploads/img2.jpg and /uploads/img4.jpg . This shows these two lines in the console.

Comment: I asked if they are valid means do you see any image when you visit `localhost:3000/uploads/img4.jpg`

Comment: No, I don't show any image

Comment: No, I don't show any image. I posted a screenshot of my images directory path along with the question. Kindly go upward and check if I am giving the correct path or not.

Comment: According to the screenshot you are storing the images in the `src` folder, you cannot access the files in your src directly. I would suggest move the uploads folder into your public directory